# MS Access form on different screen resolutions

Tags: forms, ms-access, screen-resolution

I have created a form on MS Access.  My screen resolution is 1920 X 1080.  The form fits the screen with no issues.  When someone else is using the form on their computer, they have to scroll down to view the entire form.  I suspected that they had a lower screen resolution and that was the cause.  But in fact, their resolution was set to 3840 x 2160 (which was also the "recommended" one by windows).  MS Access is maximized to the full screen size.  I do not understand why they cannot view the entire form.  With the higher res, i would expect that there would be more empty space on the form.  Can anyone explain this and provide any suggestions?